# Sbt error resolving mvn repository dependency

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I'm trying to add [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-services/6.0.1) java dependency to my scala project but when I run sbt,it says:

```
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec/working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec-working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com.pom
[warn] ==== sbt-maven-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec/working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec-working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com.pom
[warn] ==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/jboss/spec/javax/xml/bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec/working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec-working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec/working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind/jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec/working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]  module not found: org.reactivestreams#reactive-streams;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com
....
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind#jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.reactivestreams#reactive-streams;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: javax.validation#validation-api;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation#jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: javax.activation#activation;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: net.jcip#jcip-annotations;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-annotations;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging-processor;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: junit#junit;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.glassfish.jaxb#jaxb-runtime;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: com.sun.mail#javax.mail;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.james#apache-mime4j;working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/kronolynx/8365082694425c62e2152623d54b6209) is the full sbt log.

I don't understand why the version segment is `working@HP022L.corp.umbrella.com` instead of a version number.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction to solve this error.

this is my build.sbt:

```scala
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.umbrella"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "Umbrella"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "custom-mapper",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      scalaTest % Test,
      "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-core" % "6.0.1",
      "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-server-spi" % "6.0.1" % "provided",
      "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-server-spi-private" % "6.0.1" % "provided",
      "org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs" % "jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec" % "1.0.1.Final",
      "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-admin-client" % "6.0.1",
      "org.keycloak" % "keycloak-services" % "6.0.1" % "provided" // this dependency is failing to resolve
    )
  )
```

sbt resolvers:

```
sbt:custom-mapper> show fullResolvers
[info] * Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: ))
[info] * FileRepository(local, Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=Vector(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false), FileConfiguration(true, None))
[info] * FileRepository(local-preloaded-ivy, Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(/home/vulcan/.sbt/preloaded/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=Vector(/home/vulcan/.sbt/preloaded/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false), FileConfiguration(true, None))
[info] * local-preloaded: file:////home/vulcan/.sbt/preloaded/
[info] * public: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[info] * sbt-maven-releases: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/
[info] * sbt-maven-snapshots: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/
[info] * URLRepository(typesafe-ivy-releases, Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false))
[info] * URLRepository(sbt-ivy-snapshots, Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem were the transitive dependencies and the solution was to mark the dependency as non transitive, now the project compiles.

as stated in the [sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Management.html):

> ### Disable Transitivity
>
> By default, these declarations fetch all project dependencies,
>   transitively. In some instances, you may find that the dependencies
>   listed for a project aren’t necessary for it to build. Projects using
>   the Felix OSGI framework, for instance, only explicitly require its
>   main jar to compile and run. Avoid fetching artifact dependencies with
>   either intransitive() or notTransitive(), as in this example:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.felix" % "org.apache.felix.framework" % "1.8.0" intransitive()
> ```